# ¿Cómo centrar el contenido de dos input text como si fuesen uno solo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo dos `<input type="text">` y necesito que ambos queden centrados como si fuesen uno sólo, me explico:

Existen dos campos, uno para nombre y otro para apellido, si introduzco por ejemplo "JUAN DIAZ", este texto (que serían dos `input`) visualmente queda centrado en el contenedor de color amarillo, no es exacto, pero da la apariencia.

El problema radica cuando el nombre o el apellido no tienen la misma longitud, como muestro en esta imagen:

[image: ejemplo con tres nombres diferentes]

¿Existe una forma de hacerlo sólo con CSS, centrar el texto de ambos input como si fuesen uno solo? También podría optar por JS. Lo único es que siempre deben ser dos (2) `input` centrados. Sería algo así como la función "combinar y centrar" de Excel, sólo por poner un ejemplo.

Este es el código del problema:

```css
input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;
}

.contenedor {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.centrar {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}

.nombre {
  text-align: right;
}

.apellido {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">

  <div class="centrar">
    <input class="nombre" type="text" /> <input class="apellido" type="text" />

  </div>
 <div>
```

Gracias por sus observaciones.

Comment: Hola, te recomendaria usar bootstrap. Si lo usas podés poner los dos input en un div con clase "row" y dentro de ese gran div dos con la clase "col-sm-6 col-md-6" cambiandole los numeros para que logren entrar los dos en una linea.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero eso sólo me centraría los dos input (cosa que ya tengo en una sola línea) más no el contenido de éstos como si fuesen uno solo, o me equivoco? Podrías mostrarme un ejemplo de lo que mencionas por favor?

Comment: Imagino que quieres hacerlo de esa forma para poder identificar los nombres de los apellidos; pero eso se podría solucionar con un `split` y de esa forma sólo creas un input solamente

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Ciertamente, consideras que debería abrir una nueva pregunta?

Comment: No es necesario, para eso esta sección, para dar ideas :) Déjame ver que puedo ofrecerte como respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Esto no es una buena idea de diseño ni usabilidad. Vas a acabar con apellidos en el campo del nombre, nombre en el campo de los apellidos o las dos cosas. Sin mencionar que para los usuarios puede ser frustrante no entender por qué si acaban de editar el nombre y le están dando al cursor de la derecha, no se está avanzando en el apellido. ¿Hay algún motivo para hacerlo de este modo?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias por su atenta observacion, este pequeño diseño solo lo usaría yo, por ello no tomé en cuenta la usabilidad en este caso. El motivo es únicamente visual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que buscas se puede hacer con una variable css (`--value`) y agregando listeners a los inputs, de modo que cuando se agregue texto a estos, su tamaño se modifique según el tamaño del texto.

Sabemos que el tamaño de ambos en total es `300px` por tanto cada uno tiene `150px` cuando están en equilibrio, luego podemos suponer que cada carácter agrega `4px` al tamaño del input, guardando los tamaños de los textos introducidos en variables podemos hacer cálculos para asignar tamaño a los inputs a través de la variable css.

El código queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
l1=0;
l2=0;

var inputN = document.getElementsByClassName("nombre")[0];
inputN.style.setProperty("--value", 150);
inputN.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
   l1=inputN.value.length;
   val=150+l1*4-l2*4;
   inputN.style.setProperty("--value", val);
   inputA.style.setProperty("--value", 300-val);
},false);

var inputA = document.getElementsByClassName("apellido")[0];
inputA.style.setProperty("--value", 150);
inputA.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
   l2=inputA.value.length;
   val=150+l2*4-l1*4;
   inputN.style.setProperty("--value", 300-val);
   inputA.style.setProperty("--value", val);
},false);
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.contenedor {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.centrar {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}

.nombre {
  text-align: right;
  width: calc(var(--value)*1px);
}

.apellido {
  text-align: left;
  width: calc(var(--value)*1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">

  <div class="centrar">
    <input class="nombre" type="text" /> 
    <input class="apellido" type="text" />

  </div>
 <div>
```

De ese modo el texto se ve centrado sin que afecte la diferencia de tamaño entre nombre y apellido.

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Increíble, despúes de que muchos me decían que era imposible y debía plantearmelo de otro manera, llegas y me das una solución que desconocía. Mil gracias por su ayuda caballero.

Comment: @EMCode de nada, que tengas buen día.

Answer (score 5):

Una solución podría ser la siguiente:

- Creamos 2 elementos ocultos con ancho dinámico, en los que vamos a guardar el `nombre` y el `apellido`, respectivamente.
- Cada vez que se escriba en alguno de los campos, copiamos el valor de este en uno de los elementos ocultos.
- Estos elementos ocultos al ser de ancho dinámico, podemos usar [`el.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) para obtener el **ancho real del texto**
- Luego para determinar el ancho que debe tener el `input` debemos usar la formula:

  ```
  [ancho_input_nombre] = 150 + (([ancho_texto_nombre] - [ancho_texto_apellido]) / 2)
  // y viceversa para apellido
  ```
- **IMPORTANTE** Para que el cálcuo del ancho del texto funcione correctamente, es necesario que tanto los `input` como los `elementos ocultos` tengan los mismos estilos de fuente.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre'),
  apellido = document.getElementById('apellido'),
  nombreText = document.getElementById('nombreText'),
  apellidoText = document.getElementById('apellidoText');

nombre.addEventListener('input', () => {
  nombreText.innerText = nombre.value;
  centrarInputs();
});

apellido.addEventListener('input', () => {
  apellidoText.innerText = apellido.value;
  centrarInputs();
});

function centrarInputs() {
  nombre.style.width = (150 + (nombreText.offsetWidth - apellidoText.offsetWidth) / 2) + 'px';
  apellido.style.width = (150 + (apellidoText.offsetWidth - nombreText.offsetWidth) / 2) + 'px';
}
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 150px;
}
.contenedor {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 4rem;
}
.centrar {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}
.fontStyle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 16px bold Arial;
}
#nombre {
  text-align: right;
}
#apellido {
  text-align: left;
}
.ocultar {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="centrar">
    <input id="nombre" type="text" class="fontStyle" autocomplete="off" />
    <input id="apellido" type="text" class="fontStyle" autocomplete="off" />
    <span id="nombreText" class="fontStyle ocultar"></span>
    <span id="apellidoText" class="fontStyle ocultar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la alternativa que planteas en tu solución. Es una respuesta más que valida y espero sirva a otras personas. Quedo agradecido @Marcos

Answer (score 4):

Mi solución sería crear solamente un `input` en tu `DOM` y manejar mediante **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)** y **[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)** la obtención de los nombres y apellidos

```js
function process() {
  let data = $('#fullname').val()
  let firstname
  let lastname

  switch(data.split(' ').length) {
    case 3:
      firstname = data.split(' ').slice(0, 1).join(' ')
      lastname = data.split(' ').slice(-2).join(' ')
      break;
    case 4:
      firstname = data.split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' ')
      lastname = data.split(' ').slice(-2).join(' ')
      break;
  }
  
  alert(`Nombres ${firstname} | Apellidos ${lastname}`)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Ingrese nombre completo" id="fullname">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default mt-2" onclick="process()">Procesar</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Con `split` separas en un arreglo la cadena que deseas mediante la condición entregada como parámetro, que en este caso sería ' ' (*espacio en blanco*); y con `slice` obtienes una parte de la cadena de acuerdo al largo del nombre completo, ya que se puede dar el caso de tener uno a *N* nombres. 
De hecho lo tedioso de esta solución es eso, manejar las posibles opciones de nombres =/

> PD: Para implementar esto debes incluir **[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/)** y **[jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)**

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :)

Comment: A esta solución le faltan algunos casos en el switch (tal y como está ahora sólo funciona para 3 o 4 palabras, pero hay gente que sólo tiene un nombre y un apellido). Aparte de eso, el usuario puede ahorrarse incluir jQuery si sustituye `$('#fullname').val()` por `document.querySelector("#fullname").value`. Y tampoco hace falta añadir Bootstrap si el usuario mantiene su código HTML (reduciéndolo a un solo campo con id "fullname").

Comment: No quise seguir con los otros case porque pretendo dejar al OP algo de trabajo, mi idea siempre al responder es tratar de, además de enseñar apliquen un poco de su cosecha para motivar la mente. En cuanto a la alternativa de quitar JQuery, excelente! Y Bootstrap lo uso, ya que definitivamente mi fuerte no es el diseño

Comment: Hola Paulo, claro que voy a investigar más por mi cuenta, te agradezco el tiempo y tu ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Te muestro mi ejemplo acá que se puede poner código

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" id="fecha_desde" name="fecha_desde" class="input-group date form-control form-inline" date="" data-date-format="Y-m-d H:i:s" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" id="fecha_hasta" name="fecha_hasta" class="input-group date form-control" date="" data-date-format="Y-m-d H:i:s" required>
            </div>
```

Y la foto del resultado
[image: resultadohtml]
Recordá que si utilizas bootstrap tenes que incluir las librerias css y js

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por tomarte el tiempo Sabrina, acabo de editar mi pregunta, a lo mejor no me di a entender bien. Gracias

Comment: Sí, esa configuración ya la tengo en mis clases `.nombre` y `.apellido` pero funciona si los dos input tienen la misma logintud en sus caracteres

Comment: Barbaro, ahora si se entiende. Nunca me tocó hacer algo así pero podrías investigar como manejar los márgenes de cada input dependiendo del texto que  contenga. EDIT: Lo veo complicado o lo desconozco.

Comment: Igualmente agradezco tu intención y tu aporte